# CXF interceptors, SoapFaults, and custom exceptions

Tags: web-services, cxf

I'm trying to modify my CXF/Spring based SOAP web service into using interceptors to
capture SoapFaults and convert them into custom exceptions. The goal here is to
present a web client with only instances of my custom exception class when things go wrong,
never a SoapFault.

This is what I've managed to scrape together so far. You'd think there'd be more on
proper error handling in the various tuts and books , oh well.

FormsEndpointException

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class FormsEndpointException extends Exception
{
    @XmlElement(name="errMsg")
    private String myMsg
...
```

FormsEndpointImpl

```
@WebService( endpointInterface="mycorp.forms.web.endpoint.FormsEndpoint")
@org.apache.cxf.interceptor.InInterceptors (interceptors = {"mycorp.forms.web.resolver.MyExceptionInterceptor"})

public class FormsEndpointImpl implements FormsEndpoint
{
    @Resource
    WebServiceContext context;

    FormTemplateService  formTemplateService;   //injected from bean

    // must have default constructor per JAXB
    public FormsEndpointImpl() {}

    //only need setters
    public void setFormTemplateService(FormTemplateService formTemplateService) {
        this.formTemplateService = formTemplateService;
    }

    //methods    
    @WebMethod public void insertFormTemplate( FormTemplate formTemplate) throws FormsEndpointException
    {
        try {
            formTemplateService.persist(formTemplate);
        } catch ( Exception e) {
            throw new FormsEndpointException( e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    ....
}
```

MyExceptionInterceptor

```
public class MyExceptionInterceptor extends AbstractSoapInterceptor
{
    //special constructor
    public MyExceptionInterceptor()
    {
        super( Phase.USER_LOGICAL);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(SoapMessage arg0) throws Fault
    {
        //left blank for normal stuff    
    }

    //only gets called when unwinding a chain when an exception is called on that chain
    // Every exception will be wrapped into a Fault object by CXF
    @Override
    public void handleFault(SoapMessage arg0)
    {
        Fault aNewFault = new Fault( arg0.getContent(Exception.class));
        aNewFault.setFaultCode( new QName("SNAP"));
        aNewFault.setMessage("DAMMIT");
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Throwable FormsEndpointException = new FormsEndpointException("Awww");
    }
}
```

application-context.xml

```
...
<!-- Spring manage ServiceBean -->
<bean id="formsEndpoint" class="mycorp.forms.web.endpoint.FormsEndpointImpl">
  <property name="formTemplateService"  ref="formTemplateService" />
</bean>

<!-- JAX-WS Service Endpoint -->    
<jaxws:endpoint id="formsServiceService" implementor="#formsEndpoint" address="/formsService">
  <jaxws:inFaultInterceptors>
    <ref class="mycorp.forms.web.resolver.MyExceptionInterceptor" />
  </jaxws:inFaultInterceptors>
  <jaxws:outFaultInterceptors>
    <ref class="mycorp.forms.web.resolver.MyExceptionInterceptor" />
  </jaxws:outFaultInterceptors>
</jaxws:endpoint>
...
```

Question is, what needs to go into handleFault() to throw a new instance of MyException?

TIA,

Still-learning Steve

Comment: "The goal here is to present a web client with only instances of my custom exception class when things go wrong". I'm not clear what you are trying to achieve (maybe you aren't either!). The request from your client to your web service is over HTTP(S) using SOAP. Your client doesn't know (or care) that you are using Spring and Java to implement the services. So, you should be using the error handling built into the SOAP protocol (or failing that use the HTTP error codes) - you can't throw a Java exception from your server-side web services back to your client.